# Can ASP.NET application on another domain integrate with Mysql Database on another domain

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing an application using c# ASP.NET for a client already using PHP application with Mysql database on webhost site that does not support C# ASP.NET hosting. However, the application I am developing will be hosted on another server. The client want me to integrate this application with this Mysql database on another domain to be able to retrieve some data for use on the ASP.NET application. My question is then can I achieve this and if possible , how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can as long as the network administrators will allow opening the MySQL port from that server to your ASP.NET server IP address. You have to contact the network administrators to do this.

Once that is done there is no difference where the servers are located (on what domains at least), you just connect to the database as always.

Comment: Thank u for that quick response. Pls i want to also know can webservice from ASP.NET achieve communication with mysql database for the same purpose